# "windows-server-2016" tag edit rejected for Windows Server 2016 specific question

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question, rejected-edits

I edited the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41814338/windows-containers-win32-api and added the tags [windows-server-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2016), [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) and [docker-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-container).

The edit was approved by two reviewers but [rejected by other three with an interesting reason stated](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14979270):

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Awesome.

Lets start with the end. Adding tags - unless you're adding 20 of them - does not actively harm readability. Changes aren't superfluous with the exception of using both [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) and [docker-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-container), perhaps. Even conceding that, the changes aren't superfluous with regard to the original post.

The edit does however make the post both easier to read and easier to find. It helps clueless readers understand what are these containers the question speaks of. Even if they don't know the answer, it saves OP comments saying things "I don't even know what the *topic* of the question is, here's a notification so you know I don't know!" More importantly, it helps people find the question.

Windows Containers is a Windows Server 2016-specific technology (yes, my comment there is incorrect; they don't exist on Windows 10, only on the server version). It's not unreasonable to assume that people who are interested in Windows Server technologies look mainly or exclusively at the [windows-server-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2016) (and/or [windows-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server)) tags rather than at the general [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag. Even if they do take a look at the [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag, they are more likely to miss it there since they are both less interested in this tag, and because there's a lot more question traffic there. As I look at the tags, [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) has *33 asked today, 426 this week*, while [windows-server-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2016) has *25 asked this month, 111 this year*. The general tag has more questions asked today than the relevant server tag this whole **month**. He who doesn't understand that makes the question easier to find shouldn't be allowed near a computer.

That's about the Windows Server 2016 tag. The Docker tags are useful because the Windows Containers technology was made especially to enable an efficient Docker implementation (instead of using Hyper-V). *Perhaps* Docker people (esp. those interested in Windows, given that Windows is mentioned in the question title) will have some insight about it. Perhaps not, but it's worth a try.

I've seen suggestion to write tedious (perhaps preemptive) explanations in the edit summary. That's unreasonable. I shouldn't have to fight "the Man" to make somebody else's question more accessible. Providing excruciatingly long edit summary for obvious edits because I have to anticipate unreasonable reviews is itself unreasonable too.

Another suggestion is just say "who cares?" It's not me who doesn't get an answer but rather Ahmad J. Hamad. What do I care?

I care because that seems to be the fate of questions about topics less popular than JS or Android. A question about AngularJS or React or something like that will be noticed within seconds, and in the off chance of it being something new rather then a duplicate it will probably receive an answer quite fast.

The more specialized and esoteric a question is it's harder for it to get noticed by the small minority of people who can actually answer it, and when people who (seem to) have no clue about it ruin its chances to get attention it just makes it worse.

Comment: (1) I'd say at least [windows-server] or [windows-server-2016] are definitely appropriate. I'm not familiar enough with the relevant technologies to comment on the Docker tags (in any case, it's probably unnecessary to add both [docker] and [docker-container]). (2) "Approve" and "Reject" aren't the only options -- a reviewer who agreed with only some of the tags might have used "Improve edit" or "Reject and edit" instead. (3) The message you quote is generic boilerplate for one of the predefined rejection reasons, though reviewers can choose to use a custom message instead.

Comment: @duplode: I understand the message is a generic one, chosen from a few preset options. (Otherwise it would have been a real surprise 3 people independently wrote the same words exactly. :) ) That the reviewers have chosen not to change my edit - keeping only the windows-server-2016 tag would be *reasonable* (even if not my *first preference*) IMO and I wouldn't have posted this question if that happened - means they stand behind it, doesn't it? Or do they just click with little consideration or thought and roll on? That's part of the point I was making, especially towards the end of my post.

Comment: A version-specific tag probably isn't the best idea. Assuming you are right about what they meant by "containers" (which isn't at all clear), and they were introduced in Server 2016, there is every reason to believe that they'll be supported in Server-version-the-next. And if this were actually an on-topic question that was going to get answers, those answers would continue to be relevant, because the question itself is not specific to the implementation in Server 2016.

Comment: Also, the "who cares?" is because the question is obviously off-topic and unsuitable for Stack Overflow, and you should not waste your time or the reviewers' time adding tags to off-topic questions.

Comment: @CodyGray: That's an interesting point, but almost every feature is forward compatible (notable exceptions are things like WOW/NTVDM which is unavailable starting with 2008R2 or Registry reflection and perhaps KTM/TxF/TxR starting at some future version). Your approach makes these tags almost useless. I think it's reasonable to use the version specific tag when the question is really version specific (today), to improve its visibility with the target audience, and perhaps later (when it's answered, or when a new Windows version appears) add/replace with the general tag.

Comment: Re. off-topic. You said that twice, but explained, supported, justified or substantiated it nil times. Is it because OP asked "is there an API control containers" instead of "which API creates/starts/stops/provisions containers"? That seems childish at best. And if not, how is it different from "is there/which API creates a window?", "which API signals an event?", "which API get me the CPU manufacturer and model?", "which API creates/starts/stops/modifies-files-inside a Hyper-V machine?", etc.?

Answer (score 2):

> Either way, the OP will still need to know what container system they are using, unless Microsoft made a generic container API a la DirectShow filters.

It's not clear which containers is OP talking about. There are many "containers" stuff, some which are just recently available on Windows. Your edit added Docker containers and Windows Server 2016 tags, both of which offer containers, but the question has no indication which of them it's referring to.

It will probably be closed as unclear, until OP addresses all the issues listed in the comments, one of which, the container it is talking about. In this stage, I wouldn't venture adding tags until the question is clarified.

Comment: This answer demonstrates perfectly what I said. OP wrote "Windows containers". There is a Microsoft technology called "Windows Containers". You assume - based on what? - that OP meant "any/some kind of container technology that exists on Windows" (which makes the question unclear) rather than "the specific technology called 'Windows Containers'" (which makes the question crystal clear). Given that OP used the [tag:winapi] tag, asked for "win32 apis", talked about WMI and MSDN, seems like you have to work really hard to get to that non-trivial interpretation of what he said. Good job.

Comment: @conio well, if you are so sure of that, what has that technology anything to do with docker containers?

Comment: "The Docker tags are useful because the Windows Containers technology was made especially to enable an efficient Docker implementation (instead of using Hyper-V). *Perhaps* Docker people (esp. those interested in Windows, given that Windows is mentioned in the question title) will have some insight about it. Perhaps not, but it's worth a try." Disagreeing is fine. Asking how or why do I think it may help is also fine. Asking a question that was clearly answered (even if you think the answer is wrong!) is something else. Something that shall not be named per the *be nice* policy.

Comment: And of course you have not explained how you could reach the aforementioned wondrous conclusion in light of all the facts in the original question that I noted just for you.